# image not displaying in my output page

Tags: html, css

I need to display single page as below:

http://s18.postimg.org/epvzomt0p/P_62343_Patron_Roca_Ebrochure_R2_01_1.png

I made working example in 
https://jsfiddle.net/dipchk/pua95mwg/1/

Can any one tell me what more I need to implement in css in order to look like above image

```
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one">one</div>
        <div id="two">two</div>
      </div>
    </body>

    css
    .wrapper { 
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;

    }

    .wrapper div {

       padding: 10px;
    }
    #one {
      background:url('http://s2.postimg.org/5cqv0dqwp/86278_Patron_pg4_Top.png') no-repeat;
        display: block;   
        position: absolute;
        width:70%;
        height: 50%;

    }
    #two { 
        background:url('http://s18.postimg.org/9zimjy25l/P_62343_Patron_Roca_Ebrochure_R1.jpg') no-repeat;
        position: absolute;  
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15%;
        height: 40%;

    }
```

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are trying to do?
Are you trying to create a custom border in css?
Could you edit you question so its clear to people who want to answer?

Comment: If you are using percentages for your heights you'll want to put this in your css `html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this solved

```css
body{margin:0; padding:0;background:#ddd;}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;  
  width:580px;margin:0 auto;
  padding:40px 0;
  height:500px;
}

.wrapper div {
  
}
#one {
  
}
#one img {
  width:100%;  
}
#two{position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 72px;}

#two img {    
    width: 166px;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
 
  
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one"><img src="http://s2.postimg.org/5cqv0dqwp/86278_Patron_pg4_Top.png"></div>
    <div id="two"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg43a.png"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: only frame image]

Answer (score 0):

You Just Remove

> Position:absolute;

and Do what you want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you are asking.

According to the image you showed, please check the following code.

```css
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;  
}

.wrapper div {
  
}
#one {
  background:url('http://s2.postimg.org/5cqv0dqwp/86278_Patron_pg4_Top.png') no-repeat;
    
    width:580px;
    height: 142px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#two { 
    background:url('http://s18.postimg.org/9zimjy25l/P_62343_Patron_Roca_Ebrochure_R1.jpg') no-repeat;    
    width: 580px;
    height: 924px;
    margin:0 auto;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
 
  
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it's very near can you tell me how to move my second image little upwards      2nd one is top of first one

Comment: do u want to overlap 2nd image over first?

Comment: If you want to add black strip in-between white background and that photo frame , then it is not possible. Because white background and photo frame is one image only. for that you have to take three images white background, black strip and photo frame... then only its possible

Comment: image background is different       http://s9.postimg.org/5dip1p5hb/86278_Patron_pg2.png how to implement it. do i need to put as background image to outer div

Comment: I want only frame image without background